# Existence of Bochner integral for holomorphic functions

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

In functional analysis, it is common to study operators by studying complex integrals of their resolvents. For a (bounded or unbounded) operator $O,$ the resolvent $(O - \lambda)^{-1}$ is an analytic function on the complement of the spectrum of $O.$ One approach to the functional calculus is then to define operators $f(O)$ by the integral $f(O) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int d\lambda f(\lambda) (O - \lambda)^{-1}$ over a curve that surrounds the spectrum.

I have been trying to understand the underpinnings of this theory better, and am running into some confusions. Namely, how do I know that the function $f(\lambda) (O - \lambda)^{-1}$ is Bochner integrable on a curve that surrounds the spectrum?

A simpler version of the same question is as follows. In Dunford and Schwartz's book "Linear Operators," the structure of integrals of analytic vector-valued functions is developed by using the theorem that if $F$ is a Banach-space-valued, Bochner integrable function and $x^*$ is an element of the dual space of the codomain of $F$, then we have $x^* \int F = \int x^* F.$ So in chapter III.14 of Dunford/Schwartz they claim that if $F$ is a holomorphic Banach-valued function in a domain of $\mathbb{C}$ then its integral around the boundary of that domain vanishes, because $x^* \int F = \int x^* F = 0$ for all bounded functionals $x^*$. This makes sense, but only if the integral of $F$ exists in the first place; it's not clear to me why this should always be true.

Comment: $g$ is Bochner integrable if $g$ is strongly measurable and  $\int \|g\|d\mu <\infty$

Comment: Yep, I understand this --- I wasn't clear on why $g$ should be strongly measurable. But I think I just figured it out; I posted it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out; putting the answer here in case anyone else needs it. The point is that you can prove that any continuous Banach-valued function on a bounded domain in $\mathbb{C}$ is Bochner measurable, which reduces the question of integrability to the question of whether the norm of the function is integrable.

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{C},$ and $f : \Omega \to X$ a continuous Banach-valued function. Consider a partition of $\mathbb{C}$ into a square lattice of spacing $1/n,$ where we will eventually take $n$ to infinity. For any $n,$ a finite number of squares in the lattice lie within $\Omega.$ Let $s_1, \dots, s_{N_n}$ be the squares that lie entirely within $\Omega.$ Pick some $z_j$ within each $s_j$ and define the simple function
$$f_n(z) = \sum_{j=1}^{N_n} f(z_j) \chi_{s_j}(z).$$
One can show fairly easily that the sequence $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f,$ which shows that $f$ is Bochner measurable. Along any compact Jordan curve within $\Omega,$ the function $\lVert f \rVert$ will be continuous and thus will be integral. So the function $f$ is Bochner integrable along any such curve.